# How to copy extensive objects from devtools console to jsfiddle.net

Tags: javascript, json, object, google-chrome-devtools

I need help to copy big objects to start a fiddle and i cant see how i can do it.

Anyone has do this before,  copy extensive objects from devtools console to  jsfiddle.net or a file.

Apreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done pretty easy, just use the [copy($0)](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#copyobject) function.
For example:

[image]

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos That's not a problem (they do actually return undefined :) ). The important thing is that the object json string is in the clipboard, which can be past in jsfiddle.

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos Be sure that you use correctly the copy() function and indicate an existing object.